# Adjust vertical space between paragraphs in Word 2003

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

The spacing between paragraphs in Word 2003 is too large. I wish to reduce it to between 4 and 8pt.

Things I've tried:

1. Format/Paragraph (can only increase the spacing)
2. Format/Styles and formatting, modifying the highlighted style (absolutely nothing happens if I set spacing After to 4pt, or if I check the box "don't add...".)

Neither allows me to reduce the spacing between paragraphs. (This question is not related to line spacing.)

Comment: Reducing "spacing after" on a style works for me.  Try it in a completely new document - with just two paragraphs and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Turn on paragraph marks and make sure the paragraph is terminated correctly (a "shift-enter" can look like the end of a paragraph) and (I know it sounds obvious) be careful that you are modifying the correct style...

Comment: dav1dsm1th is correct, it was a paste of text with incorrect line endings. It's not normal for me to have to scratch my head for simple things, so I had the feeling something was afoot. Add it as answer and I'll accept it. (Actually, since it was a non-issue, the question only needs to stay if mods think it's a common error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on paragraph marks and make sure the paragraph is terminated correctly (a "shift-enter" can look like the end of a paragraph) and (I know it sounds obvious) be careful that you are modifying the correct style.